# SQL-Case Statement/Maybe a Loop would work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Novice coder here, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Edited:
I have a table with thousands of ongoing projects. There are at least 10 different dates/milestones per project (which are recorded as dates, hence date1, date2 and so forth). I need to create a calculated field where depending on the max date for that one project (based on ALL the date columns), I have to set it at a specific stage in the project (see Phase column--this is the calculated field I'm trying to produce with my code). Here's the breakdown:

[image]

Not all the dates in a specific stage will be available. For example, in Project #1, date1 is filled in but not date2 or date3, and so that symbolizes that the project is still in Stage1. If date2 or date3 are also filled in, the project will still be in Stage1 because date4, date5, date6, date7, date8, date9, date10 are all nulls.

So I'm writing case statement in the select statement, but it is getting a little convoluted. The following is what I drafted for Stage 2:

```
SELECT *
    FROM datatable
    CASE WHEN date5 >= date4 
          AND date5>date3 
          AND date5>date2 
          AND date5>date1 
          AND date6=NULL 
          AND date7=NULL 
          AND date8=NULL 
          AND date9=NULL 
          AND date10=NULL 
     THEN 'Stage2'
```

And that's just for stage 2. I haven't written out the other stages. Does anyone have an easier way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand. What does the image show? The data in the table or the desired result? Do you want to select data or update data in the table? You seem to want to explain some rule, but I don't understand it.

Comment: that's bad. please tag the question with the database platform.

Comment: First, Put your CASE statement at the place of *, and second, There is no other way.

Comment: what does your table(s)  look like that stores this information

Comment: also, I don't understand the logic in your image compared with the chart.  Can you generalize how it is supposed to work?  As in, "stage is whichever field has the most recent date"

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: what if a newer date is filled in on an earlier stage? For example, what if date6 has a more recent date than date14?  Is it Stage3 or Stage 2?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to set the stage according to the last date column set in the row. As the first match in a `CASE` expression wins, this would be:

```
SELECT t.*,
  CASE
    WHEN date10 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage5'
    WHEN date9 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage4'
    WHEN date8 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage4'
    WHEN date7 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage3'
    WHEN date6 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage3'
    WHEN date5 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage2'
    WHEN date4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage2'
    WHEN date3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage1'
    WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage1'
    WHEN date1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Stage1'
    ELSE 'Stage0'
  END AS stage
FROM datatable t
ORDER BY project#;
```